# Оптимизировать запрос в проекте Django

Tags: python, django

Есть модели

```
class ProgramCategory(GenericPage):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    name_alternate = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='programs')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_programs(self):
        return self.program_set.filter(active=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('our_programs', args=[self.slug])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Program Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Program Categories'
        ordering = ['sort_order']


class Program(GenericPage):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='programs')
    cover_image_cropping = ImageRatioField('cover_image', '301x201', size_warning=True)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, null=True, blank=True)
    video_gallery = models.ForeignKey(VideoGallery, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(ProgramCategory)
    banner = models.ForeignKey(Banner, null=True, blank=True)
    promotion_banner_group = models.ForeignKey(PromotionBannerGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Program, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_promotion_banners(self):
        if self.promotion_banner_group:
            return self.promotion_banner_group.get_banners()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('program', args=[self.categories.first().slug, self.slug])

    def get_cover_image(self, category):
        return self.programcoverimage_set.filter(categories__slug=category).first()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sort_order']
```

В контекст процессоре у меня так

```
def programs(request):
    return {
        'programs_categories': ProgramCategory.objects.filter(active=True)
    }
```

Как в контекст процессоре оптимизировать запрос. Если отключить его, то всего 11 запросов идет в базу, а с ним 25 запросов. Игрался с prefetch_related - ничего не получилось.

Вот шаблон где он используется

```
<div class="row h-programs">
                {% for programs_category in programs_categories %}
                    <div class="item-section">
                        <div class="item-section__title"><h3><a style="color: black" href="{{ programs_category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ programs_category.name }}</a></h3></div>
                        <div class="item-section__image"><a href="{{ programs_category.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ programs_category.cover_image|thumbnail_url:'program_thumbnail' }}" alt=""></a></div>
                        <div class="item-section__description section">{{ programs_category.description|safe }}</div>
                        <div class="item-section__button"><a class="item-section__button-link" href="{{ programs_category.get_absolute_url }}">View More</a></div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Иеще в таком

```
<li class="menu-container__item menu-container__item_dropdown {% if page.slug == 'our-programs' %}active{% endif %}">
        <a href="{% url 'our_programs' %}">Programs</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            {% for category in programs_categories %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.name_alternate }}</a>
                <ul class="submenu_inner">
                    {% for program in category.get_programs %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'program' category.slug program.slug %}">{{ program.name }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Без шаблона, использующего programs_categories, сказать трудно

Comment: В классе ProgrammCategory в методе get_programs написал return self.program_set.filter(active=True).select_related('banner', 'gallery', 'promotion_banner_group', 'video_gallery'). Количество запросов как было так и осталось

Comment: Не вижу в этом шаблоне использования programs_categories

Comment: Да, да не та часть шаблона. Извините